# Converting a 32-bit int value into a float

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a program that reads from a file that grabs 4 bytes from that file. The below hex should be 0.5 in float:

```
00 00 00 3F
```

I currently have a method that displays integer values and would like to convert the integer from 1056964608 to 0.5. This should also be able to handle negative float numbers. Can someone explain to me how this can be done in Python 2.6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `struct` module:

```
>>> struct.unpack("<f", "\x00\x00\x00\x3f")
(0.5,)
```

If you really need to convert from the integer, rather than just from the bytes, you can do that too:

```
>>> struct.unpack("<f", struct.pack("<I", 1056964608))
(0.5,)
```

Comment: Is this able to handle negative decimal numbers too?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to use `"<i"` as the format if you're passing in a signed integer.

Comment: That being said, if you're converting from the input file to an integer and from that to a float then you're making things unnecessarily complex. Just read the float in directly. And make sure to MARK ANSWERS AS ACCEPTED when they're correct.

Comment: Sorry! I thought about doing that but the input file is immensely complex. It would be easier to do double conversions with less to write. I will try to improve on this code later but for now I just want it to display data. Thank you for the tip though! :)