# Float number to inverse order hex?

Tags: python, floating-point, hex

I have a float number (that can be positive or negative, lets use 0.5) and would like to have it converted into reverse order hexadecimal. So for the above example:

```
0.5 would output 0000003F
```

Please explain what method I can use for the above problem.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Besides, from the named accepted answer, you can derive the reverse way.

Comment: Sorry, I am still pretty new to stackoverflow. I just realized the check was clickable.

Comment: I have tried converting the value directly with a method that I have but it gave the error: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '0.5'. It was designed for int values and not float values.

Comment: I don't mean to be problematic. Somethings just need to be learned as long as someone tells me! :)

Comment: No one really explained to me how the struct method worked. I read up on it but was confused after reading it. I'll admit, I am not even a novice programmer, but I do it for fun with some files in a game. It is just for recreation on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974062/converting-a-32-bit-int-value-into-a-float), you already know [the `struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html). Just apply it the other way to get your answer:

```
struct.pack("<f", .5).encode('hex')
```

Comment: Ok, I am going to just venture a guess. Struct packs the value as a float number and displays it as a hex value? "<" probably means inverse order? >_<

Comment: I just added a link to the doc. In short, struct packs the float number in a way how it appears in memory and `<` means "little endian format", meaning that the least significant byte comes first in memory, "inversed" in a certain way, but that's just a matter of convention.

Comment: I just tried the method you provided and it gives and error:
struct.error: required argument is not a float

I am going to venture a guess and say the 0 in front of 0.5 is not helping.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to put float() into the value. It was reading it as a string.